# Sound not working after installing ubuntu 22.04 Lts on Samsung 4+ Chromebook

Tags: sound, 22.04, soundcard, linux-headers

I recently converted my CHromebook to ubuntu 22.04, all drivers seem to be working but for the sound. In sound settings, the output device is only "Dummy Output".

SPecs are as follows,

CPU: Intel celeron N4000 CPU @1.10ghz
RAM: 4GB
Graphics: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 600(GLK 2)

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Gnome 42.9